# Issues in Parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-parsing, jdom

I have already existing classes,I want to check whether there is any way to map the following XML into existing class.

**Existing XML(jdom Element)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Details>
<Uniqueno>11111</Uniqueno>
<ROWSET name="Persons">
<ROW num="1">
<Name>60821894</Name>
<Age>938338789</Age>
</ROW>
<ROW num="2">
<Name>60821894</Name>
<Age>938338789</Age>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
</Details>
```

**Existing Class**

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Details")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    class Details{
          @XmlElement(name="Uniqueno")
        String Uniqueno;
        @XmlElement(name="ROWSET")
        private Persons[] persons;

        //setters & getters
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Persons")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    class Persons{
        @XmlElement(name="name")
        String name;
        @XmlElement(name="age")
        String age;

        //setters & getters
    }
```

The issue with which I am stuck is:I have a ROW num in XML which is not able to be mapped,Is any way to map the corresponding class without changing the structure of XML?

Comment: Have you tried to create a num field in your Persons class and declare it as @XmlAttribute?

Comment: Can you please make it more clear?Thanks

Comment: See this example: http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.2/jaxws/JAXWSComplexTypeMappingAttr.html#JAXWSComplexTypeMappingAttrSchemaEx050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This Code Would work 

@XmlRootElement(name = "Details")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Details
{
    @XmlElement(name = "Uniqueno")
    String Uniqueno;   


    @XmlElement(name = "ROWSET")
    private Persons[] persons;

    // setters & getters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ROWSET")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Persons
{
    @XmlAttribute
    String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "ROW")
    private Row[] rows;


    // setters & getters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ROW")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Row
{

    @XmlAttribute
    String num;

    @XmlElement
    String Name;

    @XmlElement
    String Age;

    // setters & getters
}
```